# [Windows][NDIS] how does NdisIfAllocateNetLuidIndex find a new free NetLuidIndex?

Tags: windows, ndis

MSDN points that to construct NET_LUID one have to obtain `NetLuidIndex`.
In general, for the first appearance of a new Network Interface, this `NetLuidIndex` is generated.

The question is: How to manually generate this Index? Is there a place inside registry, where all allocated NetLuidIndices are stored (a persistent storage which has to be used for this case)?

Comment: Please use the documented API: `NdisIfAllocateNetLuidIndex`.  Messing with the registry is brittle and is likely to disappoint your customers when it falls apart.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, that indices are stored inside
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NDIS\IfTypes[interface type]\IfUsedNetLuidIndices